# Haskell Yesod get user credentials in subsite

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm writing a subsite for my yesod project, and I need to display the logged in user's name on that subsite (I'm using yesod-auth hardcoded where the type of `AuthId master = Text`).

However, the user is logged in on the master site. I'm able to get a value of type `AuthId master` using `maybeAuthId`, but I am unable to display this value because it is not an instance of `Show`.

Is there a type constraint I can put on my Handler to make sure the type of `AuthId master` derives `Show`?

```
getSubsiteHomeR :: (YesodAuth master) => HandlerT Subsite (HandlerT master IO) Html
getSubsiteHomeR = do
   lift $ do
     maid <- maybeAuthId -- I want to display the value of 'maid'
     liftIO $ print maid
     defaultLayout [whamlet|.......|]
```

EDIT: Here is the error message:

```
Could not deduce (Show (AuthId master))
    arising from a use of `print'
  from the context: YesodAuth master
    bound by the type signature for:
               getSubsiteHomeR :: YesodAuth master =>
                                     HandlerT Subsite (HandlerT master IO) Html
    at src/Subsite.hs:24:1-89
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `print maid'
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: liftIO $ print maid
  In the second argument of `($)', namely
    `do { maid <- maybeAuthId;
          liftIO $ print maid;
          defaultLayout
            (do { (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                    ((blaze-markup-0.8.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack)
                       "<p>Welcome to the Subsite!</br><a href=\"");
                  (getUrlRenderParams
                   >>=
                     (\ urender_alJ6
                        -> (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                             (toHtml
                                ((\ u_alJ7 -> urender_alJ6 u_alJ7 ...)
                                   (toParent SubsiteHomeR)))));
                  (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                    ((blaze-markup-0.8.0.0:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack)
                       "\">Subsite</br></a>\n\
                       \<a href=\"");
                  .... }) }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like all you need is a `Show (AuthId master)` constraint in your type signature:

```
getSubsiteHomeR :: (YesodAuth master, Show (AuthId master)) => HandlerT Subsite (HandlerT master IO) Html
```

Note that this requires the [`FlexibleContexts`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleContexts) language extension, which you can enable by putting `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` at the top of your source file.

Comment: I think it's `FlexibleContexts`. Yesod basically requires `{-# LANGUAGE AllTheExtensions #-}` anyway though, so author should be fine.

Comment: Heres the error when I try that change `* Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Show (AuthId master)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * In the type signature:
        getFileserverHomeR :: (YesodAuth master, Show (AuthId master)) =>
                              HandlerT Fileserver (HandlerT master IO) Html
`

Comment: @frankhucek Yes, you need `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` at the top of your source file for this to work. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Cubic adding `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` fixed the problem. Thank you! Why is this necessary though?

Comment: @frankhucek The original definition for function constraints only allowed constraints of the form `Constraint typeVariable`. The constraint we have here is more complicated than that: `Constraint (SomeTypeFunction typeVariable)`. As you've seen yourself this is useful, but isn't part of the base language (yet), which is why it rests in a language extension. I've linked an explanation page in the answer, which has some more details.